# Transaction Advance Search for Sales Order in NetSuite returning Errors when otherRefNum Operator used

Tags: web-services, wsdl, netsuite

Any idea why the below code would return an error(Failure) for its status?

```
    private SearchResult getTxns()
    {
        TransactionSearchAdvanced tsa = new TransactionSearchAdvanced();

        tsa.columns = new TransactionSearchRow();

        tsa.columns.basic = new TransactionSearchRowBasic();
        tsa.columns.basic.tranId = new SearchColumnStringField[] { new SearchColumnStringField() };

        tsa.criteria = new TransactionSearch();
        tsa.criteria.basic = new TransactionSearchBasic();

        tsa.criteria.basic.mainLine = new SearchBooleanField();
        tsa.criteria.basic.mainLine.searchValue = true;
        tsa.criteria.basic.mainLine.searchValueSpecified = true;

        tsa.criteria.basic.type = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField();
        tsa.criteria.basic.type.@operator = SearchEnumMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf;
        tsa.criteria.basic.type.operatorSpecified = true;
        tsa.criteria.basic.type.searchValue = new string[] { "_salesOrder" };

        tsa.criteria.basic.otherRefNum = new SearchTextNumberField();
        tsa.criteria.basic.otherRefNum.@operator = SearchTextNumberFieldOperator.equalTo;
        tsa.criteria.basic.type.operatorSpecified = true;
        tsa.criteria.basic.type.searchValue = new string[] { "BBnB 1001" };

        SearchResult sr = _service.search(tsa);

        return sr;
    }
```

The following is the error that is returned in the results.

**Status Code:** INVALID_SEARCH_OPERATOR 
**Status Message:** You need to provide a valid search field operator.

However, this operator appears in the NetSuite UI itself when I do a search.  Also, I find it in the NetSuite documentation [here](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/SchemaBrowser/platform/v2013_1_0/coreTypes.html#platformCoreTyp%3aSearchTextNumberFieldOperator).

I am using v2013_1_0 for the webservices version of the wsdl.

**SOLUTION**

Solution found to be in the last block of code.  Was attempting to set otherRefNum and was referencing Type.  Here is the corrected code.

```
    private SearchResult getTxns()
    {
        TransactionSearchAdvanced tsa = new TransactionSearchAdvanced();

        tsa.columns = new TransactionSearchRow();

        tsa.columns.basic = new TransactionSearchRowBasic();
        tsa.columns.basic.tranId = new SearchColumnStringField[] { new SearchColumnStringField() };

        tsa.criteria = new TransactionSearch();
        tsa.criteria.basic = new TransactionSearchBasic();

        tsa.criteria.basic.mainLine = new SearchBooleanField();
        tsa.criteria.basic.mainLine.searchValue = true;
        tsa.criteria.basic.mainLine.searchValueSpecified = true;

        tsa.criteria.basic.type = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField();
        tsa.criteria.basic.type.@operator = SearchEnumMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf;
        tsa.criteria.basic.type.operatorSpecified = true;
        tsa.criteria.basic.type.searchValue = new string[] { "_salesOrder" };

        tsa.criteria.basic.otherRefNum = new SearchTextNumberField();
        tsa.criteria.basic.otherRefNum.@operator = SearchTextNumberFieldOperator.equalTo;
        tsa.criteria.basic.otherRefNum.operatorSpecified = true;
        tsa.criteria.basic.otherRefNum.searchValue = "BBnB 1001";

        SearchResult sr = _service.search(tsa);

        return sr;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `SearchEnumMultiSelectField` operator. `equalto` is not a valid operator for this filter; you will need to use `anyOf` instead.

-- EDIT - Adapated from original comment --

A `SearchTextNumberField` does not accept an array of Strings. Instead try `tsa.criteria.basic.otherRefNum.searchValue = "BBnB 1001";`

Comment: My apologies... I had posted the wrong code.  it is any of in my original base, and then SearchTextNumberFieldOperator is the equalto.  I have edited the post to reflect this.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: My next thought is that equalTo does not accept an array of arguments. Perhaps try `tsa.criteria.basic.type.searchValue = "BBnB 1001";` instead. I don't know of any reason why the `equalTo` operator itself would not be valid.

Comment: Though your suggestion was not the "solution" it has led to it.  If you will edit your answer appropriately I will mark it as the solution.  If you look at the last block of code where I was trying to set "otherRefNum", the last two lines of code mentioned "type".  Once I changed those to "otherRefNum" it accepted searchValue as a single string as expected, and then functioned properly.  Thanks for your help in leading us to the solution.  I will edit my question with the solution.